# Visual Studio MS Access tables not reflecting changes

Tags: sql, vba, visual-studio-2013

I have a Visual Studio project that accesses a MS Access database using simple queries.
One of my insert operation query(`InsertCompany`)

```
INSERT INTO `Corporate` (`CompName`, `RID`, `NetWorth`, `Shares`, `Price`, `MktValue`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

here `Corporate` is a data table in `DalalStreetDataSet`
however when i call it from my project using

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If CorporateTableAdapter2.InsertCompany(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text, TextBox5.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Company added")
    End If
End Sub
```

the Database file does not reflect changes or any insertions

I have another such a query insertion procedure on another form but that works just fine
it addresses to another table in the same file

Comment: You will have to provide some more code so that we can see the `InsertCompany` function.

Comment: But there is no other code relavant to this part of the program

Comment: Please tell me the problems that can cause no additions to take place in my file..possibly due to passing the arguments of the query using text boxes..possibly due to parsing of data

Comment: What about `CorporateTableAdapter2`? As far as I see, this is a wrapper around your `InsertCompany` query. In addition: You have the code and the facilities to debug it, so please use these facilities and try finding the exact issue.

Comment: also my SQL query which isnt functioning properly  works only without the single quotes.

Comment: Another query addressing a different table works perfectly but requires single quotes

Comment: Single quotes are not necessary here: if you have a column or table name with spaces, you will need to use square brackets, like `INSERT INTO [Table with Spaces] ([Field with Spaces]) VALUES ('test text')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is your `INSERT` query:

It should read

```
INSERT INTO Corporate (CompName, RID, NetWorth, Shares, Price, MktValue) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The next issue may be with the data types that you're giving as parameters. However, without insight into the wrapper `CorporateTableAdapter2` there is no chance finding these kind of issues.

Comment: what code dI changed the insert query it did not help what code exactly do u require?